# Blazor Server App, not loading with too many requests

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-server-side, iis-10, .net-5

I made a small Blazor Server App on .NET 5.0 an deployed it to an IIS (v 10.0),  it worked fine while testing, but after making it public, the site sometimes wasnt loading at all. After some time I figured out that it works until a certain amount of requests is reached and then it stops loading.

For example I open 30 tabs of the site and from tab 25+ it doesnt load anymore, but for the rest it works fine. When I close some of those working, the tabs which didnt load before load properly.

I then tried testing this with the default Blazor Server App Project - Same result there. So it has something to do with the IIS I think. I tried it on 2 different IIS (Local IIS and one on another Server), same result for both.

I couldn't find any related troubleshooting suggestions, so I'd be very glad if someone else had this problem already and could help me.

Best Regards

Comment: Might be the limitation that's described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms#supported-server-iis-versions

Comment: What operating system and version are you using? Do you see this same issue when opening tabs in debug mode visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use a [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003978&view=net-5.0), when you move to another tab you can call cancel method to stop the ongoing operations.

```
    private CanecellationToken cts= new CancellationTokenSource();
    public List<Model> MyList{ get; set; }
    protected override async task OnInitializedAsync()    
    {
        var obj= await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<MyList>("/api/Model", cts.Token).ToList();
    }
    public void Dispose()
{
    cts.Cancel();
    cts.Dispose();
}
```

Check source of meziantou
[here](https://www.meziantou.net/canceling-background-tasks-when-a-user-navigates-away-from-a-blazor-component.htm)